# Pausing a for loop and wait for input by changing the active cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a For loop that runs for many iterations. I want it to run and then pause after one iteration and then wait for the user to change the active cell and press enter to start the loop again for x amounts of iterations.
First I declare three public variables:

```
Public PauseButton As Boolean
Public Iterations As Integer
Public NoPause As Boolean
```

At the start of the sub I set `Iterations = 1`. Then at the end of the for loop:

```
    If Not NoPause Then
        Iterations = Iterations - 1
        If Iterations = 0 Then
            PauseButton = True
            Do While PauseButton
                DoEvents
            Loop
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Then in another sub which is run every time you press the enter key:

```
Sub EnterPress()
    If Application.ActiveCell.Row = 1 And Application.ActiveCell.Column = 5 Then
        PauseButton = False
        Iterations = 1
    ElseIf Application.ActiveCell.Row = 1 And Application.ActiveCell.Column = 6 Then
        PauseButton = False
        Iterations = 5
    ElseIf Application.ActiveCell.Row = 1 And Application.ActiveCell.Column = 7 Then
        PauseButton = False
        Iterations = 10
    ElseIf Application.ActiveCell.Row = 1 And Application.ActiveCell.Column = 8 Then
        PauseButton = False
        Iterations = 15
    ElseIf Application.ActiveCell.Row = 1 And Application.ActiveCell.Column = 9 Then
        PauseButton = False
        Iterations = 20
    ElseIf Application.ActiveCell.Row = 1 And Application.ActiveCell.Column = 10 Then
        PauseButton = False
        Iterations = 30
    ElseIf Application.ActiveCell.Row = 1 And Application.ActiveCell.Column = 11 Then
        PauseButton = False
        Iterations = 60
    ElseIf Application.ActiveCell.Row = 1 And Application.ActiveCell.Column = 12 Then
        NoPause = True
    ElseIf Application.ActiveCell.Row = 1 And Application.ActiveCell.Column = 3 Then
        Call Plock   'The main sub
    Else
        Worksheets("Simulation").Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row + 1, Application.ActiveCell.Column).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically if the active cell is "A5" I want to resume the for loop and let it run for one iteration. If the active cell is "A6" I want to resume the for loop and let it run for five iteration etc.

The problem is that when I enter the Do While loop I can't change the cursor to another active cell.

Is this possible to solve? Or do I have to use buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you want to do, but if you simply want to pause the routine to change the activecell maybe you can try something like this:

```
Sub test()

Dim newR As Integer
Dim newC As Integer

Iterations = 1

For i = 1 To 100
    If Not NoPause Then
        Iterations = Iterations - 1
        If Iterations = 0 Then
            PauseButton = True
            Do While PauseButton
                a = MsgBox("Change active cell?", vbYesNo)
                If a = vbYes Then
                    newR = InputBox("new Row?")
                    newC = InputBox("new Column?")
                End If
                Cells(newR, newC).Activate
                EnterPress
            Loop
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! No I want to change the active cell with the arrow keys or clicking on it with the mouse. When the ```Do While PauseButton : DoEvents :  Loop``` is running I can't change it.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible. There used to be a pause command in Excel VBA a decade ago or longer that would have allowed you to do something like that, but that my understanding is that the command has been deprecated. I am not sure if there is any way of interacting with a worksheet when a macro is running anymore outside the macro as you are seeking to do.